# Building Play Framework 2.4 application with Gradle 2.6 FAILED

Tags: gradle, playframework, build

everyone!

The main problem is that I fail to build my **Play Framework 2.4.0** application with **Gradle 2.6**.

The following is my **build.gradle** file (nothing special, everything here is from the official docs on using gradle with play framework https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/play_plugin.html):

```
plugins {
    id 'play'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        name "typesafe-maven-release"
        url "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases"
    }
    ivy {
        name "typesafe-ivy-release"
        url "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases"
        layout "ivy"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

model {
    components {
        play {
            platform play: '2.4.0'
        }
    }
}
```

I used **playBinary**, **runPlayBinary** and the composite tasks one by one (such as **compilePlayBinaryRoutes**, **compilePlayBinaryTwirlTemplates** and **compilePlayBinaryScala**), however the result is essentially the same every time:

```
~/projects/QuickBlox-ChatStatsUIApp/ChatStatsUI$ gradle playBinary
:compilePlayBinaryRoutes UP-TO-DATE
:compilePlayBinaryTwirlTemplates UP-TO-DATE
:compilePlayBinaryScala
/home/qb-user/projects/QuickBlox-ChatStatsUIApp/ChatStatsUI/build/playBinary/src/compilePlayBinaryRoutes/router/Routes.scala:56: value index is not a member of object controllers.Application
    controllers.Application.index(),
                            ^
/home/qb-user/projects/QuickBlox-ChatStatsUIApp/ChatStatsUI/build/playBinary/src/compilePlayBinaryRoutes/router/Routes.scala:73: value updateSettings is not a member of object controllers.Application
    controllers.Application.updateSettings(),
                            ^
/home/qb-user/projects/QuickBlox-ChatStatsUIApp/ChatStatsUI/build/playBinary/src/compilePlayBinaryRoutes/router/Routes.scala:107: value getResource is not a member of object controllers.Application
    controllers.Application.getResource(fakeValue[String]),
                            ^
/home/qb-user/projects/QuickBlox-ChatStatsUIApp/ChatStatsUI/build/playBinary/src/compilePlayBinaryTwirlTemplates/views/html/index.template.scala:75: value get is not a member of List[String]
                        """),format.raw/*57.25*/("""<tr class=""""),_display_(/*57.37*/abbreviations/*57.50*/.get(i)),format.raw/*57.57*/("""_"""),_display_(/*57.59*/i),format.raw/*57.60*/("""" title=""""),_display_(/*57.70*/keysToParse/*57.81*/.get(i + 1)),format.raw/*57.92*/(""""><td>"""),_display_(/*57.99*/abbreviations/*57.112*/.get(i)),format.raw/*57.119*/(""" """),format.raw/*57.120*/("""sum : </td><td>"""),_display_(/*57.136*/aggrResults/*57.147*/.get(i)),format.raw/*57.154*/("""</td></tr>
                                                                                                              ^
/home/qb-user/projects/QuickBlox-ChatStatsUIApp/ChatStatsUI/build/playBinary/src/compilePlayBinaryTwirlTemplates/views/html/index.template.scala:75: value get is not a member of List[String]
                        """),format.raw/*57.25*/("""<tr class=""""),_display_(/*57.37*/abbreviations/*57.50*/.get(i)),format.raw/*57.57*/("""_"""),_display_(/*57.59*/i),format.raw/*57.60*/("""" title=""""),_display_(/*57.70*/keysToParse/*57.81*/.get(i + 1)),format.raw/*57.92*/(""""><td>"""),_display_(/*57.99*/abbreviations/*57.112*/.get(i)),format.raw/*57.119*/(""" """),format.raw/*57.120*/("""sum : </td><td>"""),_display_(/*57.136*/aggrResults/*57.147*/.get(i)),format.raw/*57.154*/("""</td></tr>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ^
/home/qb-user/projects/QuickBlox-ChatStatsUIApp/ChatStatsUI/build/playBinary/src/compilePlayBinaryTwirlTemplates/views/html/index.template.scala:75: value get is not a member of List[String]
                        """),format.raw/*57.25*/("""<tr class=""""),_display_(/*57.37*/abbreviations/*57.50*/.get(i)),format.raw/*57.57*/("""_"""),_display_(/*57.59*/i),format.raw/*57.60*/("""" title=""""),_display_(/*57.70*/keysToParse/*57.81*/.get(i + 1)),format.raw/*57.92*/(""""><td>"""),_display_(/*57.99*/abbreviations/*57.112*/.get(i)),format.raw/*57.119*/(""" """),format.raw/*57.120*/("""sum : </td><td>"""),_display_(/*57.136*/aggrResults/*57.147*/.get(i)),format.raw/*57.154*/("""</td></tr>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^
/home/qb-user/projects/QuickBlox-ChatStatsUIApp/ChatStatsUI/build/playBinary/src/compilePlayBinaryTwirlTemplates/views/html/index.template.scala:75: value get is not a member of List[Long]
                        """),format.raw/*57.25*/("""<tr class=""""),_display_(/*57.37*/abbreviations/*57.50*/.get(i)),format.raw/*57.57*/("""_"""),_display_(/*57.59*/i),format.raw/*57.60*/("""" title=""""),_display_(/*57.70*/keysToParse/*57.81*/.get(i + 1)),format.raw/*57.92*/(""""><td>"""),_display_(/*57.99*/abbreviations/*57.112*/.get(i)),format.raw/*57.119*/(""" """),format.raw/*57.120*/("""sum : </td><td>"""),_display_(/*57.136*/aggrResults/*57.147*/.get(i)),format.raw/*57.154*/("""</td></tr>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ^
/home/qb-user/projects/QuickBlox-ChatStatsUIApp/ChatStatsUI/build/playBinary/src/compilePlayBinaryTwirlTemplates/views/html/index.template.scala:158: value get is not a member of List[String]
                        document.getElementById('timeLength').value = '"""),_display_(/*140.73*/timeLengths/*140.84*/.get(1)),format.raw/*140.91*/("""'""")))}/*140.94*/else/*140.99*/{_display_(Seq[Any](format.raw/*140.100*/("""
                                                                                                                      ^
/home/qb-user/projects/QuickBlox-ChatStatsUIApp/ChatStatsUI/build/playBinary/src/compilePlayBinaryTwirlTemplates/views/html/index.template.scala:182: value get is not a member of List[String]
                                        """),format.raw/*164.41*/("""<span title=""""),_display_(/*164.55*/keysToParse/*164.66*/.get(i + 1)),format.raw/*164.77*/("""" class=""""),_display_(/*164.87*/abbreviations/*164.100*/.get(i)),format.raw/*164.107*/("""_"""),_display_(/*164.109*/i),format.raw/*164.110*/(""""><input type="checkbox" id=""""),_display_(/*164.140*/i),format.raw/*164.141*/("""" checked onclick="change(this)">"""),_display_(/*164.175*/abbreviations/*164.188*/.get(i)),format.raw/*164.195*/("""</span>
                                                                                                                                 ^
/home/qb-user/projects/QuickBlox-ChatStatsUIApp/ChatStatsUI/build/playBinary/src/compilePlayBinaryTwirlTemplates/views/html/index.template.scala:182: value get is not a member of List[String]
                                        """),format.raw/*164.41*/("""<span title=""""),_display_(/*164.55*/keysToParse/*164.66*/.get(i + 1)),format.raw/*164.77*/("""" class=""""),_display_(/*164.87*/abbreviations/*164.100*/.get(i)),format.raw/*164.107*/("""_"""),_display_(/*164.109*/i),format.raw/*164.110*/(""""><input type="checkbox" id=""""),_display_(/*164.140*/i),format.raw/*164.141*/("""" checked onclick="change(this)">"""),_display_(/*164.175*/abbreviations/*164.188*/.get(i)),format.raw/*164.195*/("""</span>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ^
/home/qb-user/projects/QuickBlox-ChatStatsUIApp/ChatStatsUI/build/playBinary/src/compilePlayBinaryTwirlTemplates/views/html/index.template.scala:182: value get is not a member of List[String]
                                        """),format.raw/*164.41*/("""<span title=""""),_display_(/*164.55*/keysToParse/*164.66*/.get(i + 1)),format.raw/*164.77*/("""" class=""""),_display_(/*164.87*/abbreviations/*164.100*/.get(i)),format.raw/*164.107*/("""_"""),_display_(/*164.109*/i),format.raw/*164.110*/(""""><input type="checkbox" id=""""),_display_(/*164.140*/i),format.raw/*164.141*/("""" checked onclick="change(this)">"""),_display_(/*164.175*/abbreviations/*164.188*/.get(i)),format.raw/*164.195*/("""</span>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^
11 errors found
:compilePlayBinaryScala FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compilePlayBinaryScala'.
> Compilation failed

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.445 secs
```

And here's the structure of the **build** directory, after build failure:

```
build
├── playBinary
│   ├── classes
│   └── src
│       ├── compilePlayBinaryRoutes
│       │   ├── controllers
│       │   │   ├── javascript
│       │   │   │   └── JavaScriptReverseRoutes.scala
│       │   │   ├── ReverseRoutes.scala
│       │   │   └── routes.java
│       │   └── router
│       │       ├── RoutesPrefix.scala
│       │       └── Routes.scala
│       └── compilePlayBinaryTwirlTemplates
│           └── views
│               └── html
│                   └── index.template.scala
└── tmp
    └── compilePlayBinaryScala
```

My guess is that it might have something to do with the fact, that Gradle 2.6 doesn't support reverse routing for now. I tried creating a new Play application (2.4.2 this time) and built it straight away, however it also failed on the same part:

```
controllers.Application.index(),
                                         ^
```

Comment: If you migrate from 2.3 - you need to move all files from `conf` to `main/scala/resources`. Follow migration guide, and check 2.4 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

So let's go one by one:

1. All the errors after the first 3 were my mistakes, but I somehow assumed, that they were caused by the first 3. All of those were basically the result of not proper treating of the data structures in scala (my bad, I'm a noob there).
2. The first 3 however were caused by the fact, that I had non-static methods in my main Controller. Somehow, I must have overlooked the fact, that you have to prefix your non-static methods calls in **routes** file with a '@' sign. So the solution is to either place the prefix in the **routes** file, or make methods static.

The only reference to this (static/non-static behavior), that I found is a scarce mentioning here (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0/JavaRouting#Dependency-Injection [last line of this paragraph]).